# OpenGLES rendering both triangle sides, alpha don't working

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to render a cube with a texture on its sides, on OpenGLES 2.0 iOS. Part of the texture has an alpha transparency, and I want to see the back of the face that is behind it. To render both sides of the cube side, I've used

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

and to enable transparency,

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

before drawing. And my cubes are rendered creating instances of the following class:

```
// In MSTexturedCube.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface MSTexturedCube : NSObject {
    GLKVector3 _vertices[8];
    GLKVector3 _triangleVertices[36];
    GLKVector2 _textureVertices[36];
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float xRotationAngle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float yRotationAngle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLKVector3 scale;             // x, y, z scale
@property (nonatomic, assign) GLKVector3 translation;   // x, y, z translation

- (id)initWithTexture:(GLKTextureInfo *)textureInfo vertexData:(GLKVector2[36])textureVertexData;
- (id)initWithTexture:(GLKTextureInfo *)textureInfo frontFaceCoords:(GLKVector2[4])front right:(GLKVector2[4])right back:(GLKVector2[4])back left:(GLKVector2[4])left top:(GLKVector2[4])top bottom:(GLKVector2[4])bottom;

- (void)draw;

- (void)setVertices:(GLKVector3[8])verticesArray;

@end



// In MSTexturedCube.m
#import "MSTexturedCube.h"

static int vertexIndices[36] = {
    // Front
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    // Right
    1, 5, 6,
    1, 6, 2,
    // Back
    5, 4, 7,
    5, 7, 6,
    // Left
    4, 0, 3,
    4, 3, 7,
    // Top
    3, 2, 6,
    3, 6, 7,
    // Bottom
    4, 5, 1,
    4, 1, 0,
};

@interface MSTexturedCube ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) GLKBaseEffect *effect;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo;

- (void)setupOpenGL;

@end

@implementation MSTexturedCube

@synthesize effect = _effect;
@synthesize textureInfo = _textureInfo;

@synthesize xRotationAngle = _xRotationAngle;
@synthesize yRotationAngle = _yRotationAngle;
@synthesize scale = _scale;
@synthesize translation = _translation;

// Init methods
...

- (void)draw {
    // Create matrices
    GLKMatrix4 yRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeYRotation(self.yRotationAngle);
    GLKMatrix4 xRotation = GLKMatrix4MakeXRotation(self.xRotationAngle);
    GLKMatrix4 scale = GLKMatrix4MakeScale(self.scale.x, self.scale.y, self.scale.z);
    GLKMatrix4 translation = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(self.translation.x, self.translation.y, self.translation.z);

    GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(translation, GLKMatrix4Multiply(xRotation, GLKMatrix4Multiply(yRotation, scale)));
    GLKMatrix4 viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(0.25 * M_PI, 1.0, 2.0, 500.0);

    // Set texture properties if a texture is set
    if (self.textureInfo) {
        self.effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
        self.effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
        self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
    }

    // Prepare the effect to draw after creating matrices
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    // Set texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(self.textureInfo.target, self.textureInfo.name);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

    // Set vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, _triangleVertices);

    // Set texture (if set)
    if (self.textureInfo) {
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, _textureVertices);
    }

    // Draw
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    // Disable arrays
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
}

// Getters & setters
...

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)setupOpenGL {
    // Set vertices array
    _vertices[0] = GLKVector3Make(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5); // Left  bottom front
    _vertices[1] = GLKVector3Make( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5); // Right bottom front
    _vertices[2] = GLKVector3Make( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5); // Right top    front
    _vertices[3] = GLKVector3Make(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5); // Left  top    front
    _vertices[4] = GLKVector3Make(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5); // Left  bottom back
    _vertices[5] = GLKVector3Make( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5); // Right bottom back
    _vertices[6] = GLKVector3Make( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5); // Right top    back
    _vertices[7] = GLKVector3Make(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5); // Left  top    back

    // Set the triangle vertices
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        _triangleVertices[i] = _vertices[vertexIndices[i]];
    }

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I create a cube with the front face transparent and all the others opaque, this face acts as if there were nothing behind, showing the background. However, if I put a smaller opaque cube inside, it's rendered perfectly and I can see it through the transparent face of the biggest cube. Does anyone know why this happens, and how I could fix it?

Thanks in advance! If you need more information about my code, ask me.

Comment: Could you add the code where you fill _textureVertices.

Comment: They are hard-coded... I'm not on my computer now, but I'll post them as soon as I can.

Comment: Sounds like you should disable writing to depth buffer too.

Comment: But if I do so, the opaque cubes won't display as they do now, will them?

Comment: I have implemented a kind of workaround which works that I will post as an answer and accept. However, if somebody provides a "cleaner" answer, I will accept it instead mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented a workaround. It consists in creating two MSTexturedCube objects, with exactly the same vertices and texture vertices, and render one with cull facing enabled and `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`, and the other one with `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)`. It works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that transparent side was rendered first in your case and filled depth buffer, back sides did not pass depth test and were not drawn. To solve this you can draw opaque and transparent objects separately, first opaque ones then transparent, also you will have to draw transparent objects from back to front. Another option is to use discard for fully transparent pixels, but this only works for fully transparent case and usually quite slow.